# Fundamental groups of compact manifolds with non-negative Ricci curvature.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, reference-request

I would like to find an appropriate reference for the following statement:

**Statement.** Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with non-negative Ricci curvature.
Then $\pi_1(M)$ is virtually abelian.

It seems to me that the statement should follow from the article of Cheeger and Gromoll 
"The spletting theorem for manifolds of non-negative Ricci curvature"
http://intlpress.com/JDG/archive/1972/6-1-119.pdf
but since it is not stated explicitly in the article I am not 100% sure.

So, what would be a reference?

Comment: Is it not precisely Theorem 3 (pag 126) in the paper by Cheeger and Gromoll? 

Comment: Francesco, huge thanks! Of course you are right, I overlooked this theorem (shame for me :) ... ). 


Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following paper has more than you want.

[Wilking, Burkhard On fundamental groups of manifolds of nonnegative curvature. Differential Geom. Appl. 13 (2000), no. 2, 129–165.](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/sfb/about/publ/wilking3.ps)

Comment: The link seems dead.  Here's an alternative:  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224500000309, or a free one here: https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/theoretische_mathematik/diffgeo/mr1783960.pdf